# parse error in zend module.config.php line 78

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am getting this error, can somebody help..

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/zendd/module/Application/config/module.config.php on line 76

here is my code

```
'Application\Controller\Index' => Controller\IndexController::class
```

Error is pointing at this line in module.config.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Zend Framework (http://framework.zend.com/)
 *
 * @link      http://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication     for the canonical source repository
* @copyright Copyright (c) 2005-2015 Zend Technologies USA Inc.     (http://www.zend.com)
* @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
*/
namespace Application;
return array(
'router' => array(
'routes' => array(
'home' => array(
'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
'options' => array(
'route'    => '/',
'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        // The following is a route to simplify getting started creating
        // new controllers and actions without needing to create a new
        // module. Simply drop new controllers in, and you can access them
        // using the path /application/:controller/:action
        'application' => array(
            'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/application',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'Index',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'default' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
'service_manager' => array(
    'abstract_factories' => array(
        'Zend\Cache\Service\StorageCacheAbstractServiceFactory',
        'Zend\Log\LoggerAbstractServiceFactory',
    ),
    'factories' => array(
        'translator' => 'Zend\Mvc\Service\TranslatorServiceFactory',
    ),
),
'translator' => array(
    'locale' => 'en_US',
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type'     => 'gettext',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
        ),
    ),
),
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Application\Controller\Index' => Controller\IndexController::class
    ),
),
'view_manager' => array(
    'display_not_found_reason' => true,
    'display_exceptions'       => true,
    'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
    'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
    'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
    'template_map' => array(
        'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
        'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
        'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
        'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
    ),
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
// Placeholder for console routes
'console' => array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
        ),
    ),
),
```

);

Comment: Does your code look like that?  Have you considered indenting / formatting your code?  Helps a lot to see syntax errors. ... Ah much better

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. here is the full code it points at 76 which is 'Application\Controller\Index' => Controller\IndexController::class

Comment: Is the controller method called `class`?  Might be a [reserved/ keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php) issue?  Sorry, not too familiar with ZF2 configs.  Simple test would be to rename `class` to `foo` and see if error changes.

Comment: this is a skeleton-application-master downloaded from github and it gives this error. first time trying to work with zend.

Comment: if i change class to foo . it gives  Undefined class constant 'foo'

Comment: What's your PHP Version?

Comment: i mean version 5.4.7

Comment: Pretty sure that would need 5.5 > verify that is not the issue?

Comment: Thanks @ficuscr . was fixed after i updated to 5.5. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need to use PHP 5.5 or greater.  See:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class

You'll note the gist you copied from says "Application config with PHP 5.5 ::class style"